# Extract text from an href recursively with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

We have the following HTML:

```
<a class="link contact-info__link" href="tel:+99999999999">
    <svg class="icon icon--telephone contact-info__link-icon contact-info__link-icon--phone">
        <use xlink:href="/local/templates/.default/img/icon-font/icon-font.svg#icon-phone"></use>
    </svg>
    <span class="contact-info__link-text">+9 (999) 999-99-99</span>
</a>
```

I need to get this dictionary:

```
{"tel:+99999999999": "+9 (999) 999-99-99"}
```

That is, I need the `href` link and the respective `text`, regardless of how many "child" tags there are after the `href`. In this case, I need the `href` link itself and the `text` in the `span`, but consider that it could be `span` or any other type of tag.

I am currently using this code to get all `href` + `text` from any page (as this is the goal):

```
for r in response.css('a'):
    url = r.css('::attr(href)').get()
    txt = r.css('::text').get()
```

That works for this type of case:

```
<a href="tel:+99999999999">This is my phone</a>
```

But not when it is recursive, like the first code, it just returns this:

```
{"tel:+99999999999": "\n"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get whole text under `a` tag you can use `getall()` method and then `join` all text into one string.
This example you can use:

```py
url = r.css('::attr(href)').get()
txt = r.css('::text').getall()
txt = ''.join([t.strip() for t in txt if t.strip()]) if txt else txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
tel_s = response.css('.link contact-info__link')
yield {tel_s.css('::attr(href)').get(): tel_s.css('span::text)').get()}
```

output:

```
{"tel:+99999999999": "+9 (999) 999-99-99"}
```